# Unfortunately IrrHelloWorld has stopped - Android

Tags: java, eclipse, android-emulator, android-ndk, android-logcat

I'm working on compiling and running a sample for android port of irrlicht in Emulator using NDK.(Mac). I have compiled the sample successfully after changing settings in Eclipse, but it shows an alert showing that 'Unfortunately app has stopped'. This is what I found in my Logcat:

```
11-26 05:31:24.200: I/ActivityManager(727): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=doug.irrlicht/.IrrHelloWorld} from pid 856
11-26 05:31:24.240: E/SoundPool(727): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:24.240: W/AudioService(727): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:24.250: E/SoundPool(727): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:24.250: W/AudioService(727): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:24.250: E/SoundPool(727): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:24.250: W/AudioService(727): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:24.250: E/SoundPool(727): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:24.260: W/AudioService(727): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:24.260: E/SoundPool(727): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:24.260: W/AudioService(727): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:24.270: E/SoundPool(727): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
11-26 05:31:24.290: W/AudioService(727): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
11-26 05:31:24.300: E/SoundPool(727): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
11-26 05:31:24.300: W/AudioService(727): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
11-26 05:31:24.300: E/SoundPool(727): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
11-26 05:31:24.350: W/AudioService(727): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
11-26 05:31:24.350: E/SoundPool(727): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
11-26 05:31:24.350: W/AudioService(727): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
11-26 05:31:24.360: W/AudioService(727): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
11-26 05:31:24.400: I/WindowManager(727): Screenshot Window{41941da8 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher} was all black! mSurfaceLayer=21005 minLayer=21005 maxLayer=21005
11-26 05:31:24.621: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 0 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.632: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 1 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.641: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 2 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.641: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 3 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.641: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 4 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.641: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 5 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.641: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 6 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.641: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 7 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.641: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 8 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.651: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 9 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.651: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 10 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.651: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 11 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.651: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 12 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.651: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 13 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.661: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 14 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.661: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 15 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.661: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 16 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.661: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 17 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.661: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 18 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.661: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 19 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.661: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 20 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.661: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 21 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.671: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 22 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.671: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 23 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.671: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 24 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.671: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 25 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.671: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 26 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.681: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 27 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.681: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 28 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.681: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 29 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.691: I/ActivityManager(727): Start proc doug.irrlicht for activity doug.irrlicht/.IrrHelloWorld: pid=1195 uid=10048 gids={50048, 1028}
11-26 05:31:24.691: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 30 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.691: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 31 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.701: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 32 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.701: W/dalvikvm(1195): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 33 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-26 05:31:24.741: D/dalvikvm(1195): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
11-26 05:31:25.880: D/(1195): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a1c9188, tid 1195
11-26 05:31:25.891: D/libEGL(1195): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
11-26 05:31:25.901: D/(1195): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a1c9300, tid 1208
11-26 05:31:25.971: D/libEGL(1195): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
11-26 05:31:25.980: D/libEGL(1195): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
11-26 05:31:26.030: W/GL2JNIView(1195): creating OpenGL ES 2.0 context
11-26 05:31:26.120: D/dalvikvm(1195): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/doug.irrlicht-2/libIrrHelloWorld.so 0x416f2020
11-26 05:31:26.120: I/ActivityManager(727): Displayed doug.irrlicht/.IrrHelloWorld: +1s508ms
11-26 05:31:26.140: D/dalvikvm(1195): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/doug.irrlicht-2/libIrrHelloWorld.so 0x416f2020
11-26 05:31:26.140: D/dalvikvm(1195): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/doug.irrlicht-2/libIrrHelloWorld.so 0x416f2020, skipping init
11-26 05:31:26.220: W/dalvikvm(1195): No implementation found for native Ldoug/irrlicht/GLNative;.init:(IILdoug/irrlicht/ArchiveHelper;)I
11-26 05:31:26.230: W/dalvikvm(1195): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
11-26 05:31:26.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1195): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 66
11-26 05:31:26.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1195): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: doug.irrlicht.GLNative.init:(IILdoug/irrlicht/ArchiveHelper;)I
11-26 05:31:26.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at doug.irrlicht.GLNative.init(Native Method)
11-26 05:31:26.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at doug.irrlicht.GLNative.<init>(GLNative.java:14)
11-26 05:31:26.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at doug.irrlicht.GLView$Renderer.onSurfaceChanged(GLView.java:314)
11-26 05:31:26.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1512)
11-26 05:31:26.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
11-26 05:31:26.310: W/ActivityManager(727):   Force finishing activity doug.irrlicht/.IrrHelloWorld
11-26 05:31:26.581: D/dalvikvm(727): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 944K, 30% free 6717K/9588K, paused 170ms, total 178ms
11-26 05:31:26.691: I/WindowManager(727): Screenshot Window{418c1668 u0 Starting doug.irrlicht} was all black! mSurfaceLayer=21020 minLayer=21020 maxLayer=21020
11-26 05:31:26.861: W/EGL_emulation(856): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-26 05:31:27.250: W/InputMethodManagerService(727): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41753208 (uid=10048 pid=1195)
11-26 05:31:28.220: D/dalvikvm(727): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 592K, 27% free 7053K/9588K, paused 111ms, total 118ms
11-26 05:31:28.341: I/WindowManager(727): Screenshot Window{41941da8 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher} was all black! mSurfaceLayer=21005 minLayer=21005 maxLayer=21005
11-26 05:31:28.371: E/ActivityThread(856): Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: {com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
11-26 05:31:28.371: E/ActivityThread(856): java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: {com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
11-26 05:31:28.371: E/ActivityThread(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3031)
11-26 05:31:28.371: E/ActivityThread(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3019)
11-26 05:31:28.371: E/ActivityThread(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2997)
11-26 05:31:28.371: E/ActivityThread(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-26 05:31:28.371: E/ActivityThread(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1267)
11-26 05:31:28.371: E/ActivityThread(856):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-26 05:31:28.371: E/ActivityThread(856):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-26 05:31:28.371: E/ActivityThread(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-26 05:31:28.371: E/ActivityThread(856):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 05:31:28.371: E/ActivityThread(856):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-26 05:31:28.371: E/ActivityThread(856):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-26 05:31:28.371: E/ActivityThread(856):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-26 05:31:28.371: E/ActivityThread(856):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 05:31:29.571: I/Process(1195): Sending signal. PID: 1195 SIG: 9
11-26 05:31:29.601: I/ActivityManager(727): Process doug.irrlicht (pid 1195) has died.
11-26 05:31:29.631: E/SoundPool(727): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:29.631: W/AudioService(727): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:29.631: E/SoundPool(727): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:29.631: W/AudioService(727): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:29.631: E/SoundPool(727): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:29.631: W/AudioService(727): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:29.641: E/SoundPool(727): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:29.641: W/AudioService(727): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:29.641: E/SoundPool(727): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:29.641: W/AudioService(727): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-26 05:31:29.651: E/SoundPool(727): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
11-26 05:31:29.651: W/AudioService(727): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
11-26 05:31:29.651: E/SoundPool(727): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
11-26 05:31:29.651: W/AudioService(727): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
11-26 05:31:29.661: E/SoundPool(727): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
11-26 05:31:29.661: W/AudioService(727): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
11-26 05:31:29.661: E/SoundPool(727): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
11-26 05:31:29.661: W/AudioService(727): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
11-26 05:31:29.661: W/AudioService(727): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
11-26 05:31:29.771: W/InputMethodManagerService(727): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@418fa370 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@41c81638
```

Here is my Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /Users/karthik/android/irrlichtandroid/project/include
LOCAL_MODULE    := Irrlicht
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := /Users/karthik/android/irrlichtandroid/project/libs/armeabi/libirrlicht.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := -I /Users/karthik/android/irrlichtandroid/project/include -I$(IRR_PROJECT)/include

LOCAL_MODULE    := IrrHelloWorld
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -I$(IRR_PROJECT)/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    native.cpp \
    ArchiveLoader.cpp \
    FileArchive.cpp \
    ReadFile.cpp \
    ArchiveHelper.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -L$(IRR_PROJECT)/cmake/android -llog -lGLESv2

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := Irrlicht

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I have checked again, all the folders and files , I have specified exists in exact paths.
I have googled line by line but I dint found nothing yet. Even I re-installed Eclipse, SDK and NDK. I dint found a word 'caused' in log cat. What is the actual issue? I'll provide more data clearly about project if needed by anyone. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have a link error, in which case we'd need to see the Android.mk file, or there is actually a problem with the JNI, in which case we'd need to see some C code.

Comment: Specifically, `No implementation found for native Ldoug/irrlicht/GLNative;.init:(IILdoug/irrlicht/ArchiveHelper;)I`.  So focus on `native int GLNative.init(int, int, ArchiveHelper)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue, the actual error is, it looks for assets in `mnt/sdcard/irrlicht` not inside `assets` folder, I have copied everything from my `assets` folder to `mnt/sdcard/irrlicht`, My app running successfully without crash. I have ignored the below error:

```
11-27 02:54:35.358: E/cutils-trace(927): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed that `No implementation found for native Ldoug/irrlicht/GLNative;.init:` error by adding JNIEXPORT when implementing native functions and unsatisfied linker error was due to my mistake in library name while loading. Now my log cat contains these things:

```
11-27 02:54:35.058: D/AndroidRuntime(927): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
11-27 02:54:35.058: D/AndroidRuntime(927): CheckJNI is ON
11-27 02:54:35.138: D/dalvikvm(927): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-27 02:54:35.159: D/dalvikvm(927): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-27 02:54:35.218: D/dalvikvm(927): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-27 02:54:35.218: D/dalvikvm(927): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-27 02:54:35.358: E/cutils-trace(927): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-27 02:54:36.178: D/AndroidRuntime(927): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
11-27 02:54:36.288: W/ActivityManager(276): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/IrrHelloWorld.apk
11-27 02:54:37.198: W/ActivityManager(276): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/IrrHelloWorld.apk
11-27 02:54:37.198: I/PackageManager(276): Copying native libraries to /data/app-lib/vmdl448300730
11-27 02:54:39.708: I/ActivityManager(276): Force stopping package doug.irrlicht appid=10048 user=-1
11-27 02:54:40.108: D/dalvikvm(276): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 727K, 28% free 6259K/8660K, paused 110ms, total 110ms
11-27 02:54:40.128: I/PackageManager(276): Package doug.irrlicht codePath changed from /data/app/doug.irrlicht-2.apk to /data/app/doug.irrlicht-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
11-27 02:54:41.250: I/PackageManager(276): Running dexopt on: doug.irrlicht
11-27 02:54:41.489: D/dalvikvm(938): DexOpt: load 77ms, verify+opt 28ms, 199700 bytes
11-27 02:54:41.508: I/ActivityManager(276): Force stopping package doug.irrlicht appid=10048 user=-1
11-27 02:54:41.518: W/PackageManager(276): Code path for pkg : doug.irrlicht changing from /data/app/doug.irrlicht-2.apk to /data/app/doug.irrlicht-1.apk
11-27 02:54:41.518: W/PackageManager(276): Resource path for pkg : doug.irrlicht changing from /data/app/doug.irrlicht-2.apk to /data/app/doug.irrlicht-1.apk
11-27 02:54:41.768: I/ActivityManager(276): Force stopping package doug.irrlicht appid=10048 user=0
11-27 02:54:41.919: D/dalvikvm(406): GC_EXPLICIT freed 124K, 26% free 9364K/12652K, paused 5ms+16ms, total 133ms
11-27 02:54:42.018: D/dalvikvm(431): GC_EXPLICIT freed 135K, 13% free 2845K/3244K, paused 5ms+14ms, total 183ms
11-27 02:54:42.178: I/InputReader(276): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
11-27 02:54:42.268: D/BackupManagerService(276): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:doug.irrlicht flg=0x8000010 (has extras) }
11-27 02:54:42.328: W/ContextImpl(788): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1385 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:473 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:473 com.android.keychain.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:12 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:2424 
11-27 02:54:42.569: D/BackupManagerService(276): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:doug.irrlicht flg=0x8000010 (has extras) }
11-27 02:54:42.618: V/BackupManagerService(276): removePackageParticipantsLocked: uid=10048 #1
11-27 02:54:42.628: I/InputReader(276): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
11-27 02:54:42.678: V/BackupManagerService(276): addPackageParticipantsLocked: #1
11-27 02:54:43.369: I/Choreographer(406): Skipped 164 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 02:54:44.458: I/Choreographer(406): Skipped 208 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 02:54:45.038: D/dalvikvm(406): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3731K, 40% free 7603K/12652K, paused 78ms, total 96ms
11-27 02:54:45.228: I/Choreographer(406): Skipped 77 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 02:54:46.468: D/dalvikvm(276): GC_EXPLICIT freed 805K, 30% free 6093K/8660K, paused 294ms+50ms, total 2164ms
11-27 02:54:46.678: D/dalvikvm(406): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 304K, 30% free 8975K/12652K, paused 58ms, total 60ms
11-27 02:54:46.939: I/Choreographer(406): Skipped 92 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 02:54:47.052: W/RecognitionManagerService(276): no available voice recognition services found for user 0
11-27 02:54:47.058: D/AndroidRuntime(927): Shutting down VM
11-27 02:54:47.068: D/dalvikvm(927): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-27 02:54:48.048: D/AndroidRuntime(943): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
11-27 02:54:48.048: D/AndroidRuntime(943): CheckJNI is ON
11-27 02:54:48.108: D/dalvikvm(943): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-27 02:54:48.128: D/dalvikvm(943): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-27 02:54:48.188: D/dalvikvm(943): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-27 02:54:48.188: D/dalvikvm(943): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-27 02:54:48.298: E/cutils-trace(943): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-27 02:54:49.088: D/AndroidRuntime(943): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-27 02:54:49.108: D/dalvikvm(943): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 163 unimplemented (abstract) methods
11-27 02:54:49.139: I/ActivityManager(276): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=doug.irrlicht/.IrrHelloWorld} from pid 943
11-27 02:54:49.209: W/WindowManager(276): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21005
11-27 02:54:49.269: D/AndroidRuntime(943): Shutting down VM
11-27 02:54:49.269: D/jdwp(943): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
11-27 02:54:49.269: D/dalvikvm(943): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-27 02:54:49.289: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 0 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.289: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 1 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.298: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 2 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.298: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 3 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.298: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 4 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.298: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 5 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.298: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 6 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.298: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 7 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.298: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 8 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.298: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 9 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.298: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 10 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.298: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 11 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.298: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 12 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.298: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 13 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.309: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 14 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.309: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 15 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.309: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 16 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.309: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 17 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.309: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 18 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.309: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 19 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.309: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 20 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.309: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 21 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.318: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 22 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.318: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 23 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.318: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 24 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.318: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 25 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.318: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 26 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.318: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 27 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.318: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 28 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.318: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 29 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.318: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 30 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.318: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 31 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.318: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 32 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.318: W/dalvikvm(954): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 33 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 02:54:49.338: I/ActivityManager(276): Start proc doug.irrlicht for activity doug.irrlicht/.IrrHelloWorld: pid=954 uid=10048 gids={50048, 1015, 1028}
11-27 02:54:49.349: I/Choreographer(406): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 02:54:49.408: D/dalvikvm(954): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
11-27 02:54:51.308: D/libEGL(954): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
11-27 02:54:51.328: D/libEGL(954): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
11-27 02:54:51.378: I/Choreographer(954): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 02:54:51.548: D/gralloc_goldfish(954): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-27 02:54:51.558: W/dalvikvm(954): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
11-27 02:54:51.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 84
11-27 02:54:51.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
11-27 02:54:51.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at doug.irrlicht.GLView$ConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLView.java:149)
11-27 02:54:51.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1024)
11-27 02:54:51.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1401)
11-27 02:54:51.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
11-27 02:54:51.588: W/ActivityManager(276):   Force finishing activity doug.irrlicht/.IrrHelloWorld
11-27 02:54:51.911: I/WindowManager(276): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{4181b720 ActivityRecord{41884410 u0 doug.irrlicht/.IrrHelloWorld}} appWin=Window{418cd018 u0 Starting doug.irrlicht} drawState=4
11-27 02:54:51.911: W/WindowManager(276): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (480x800) to layer 21020
11-27 02:54:52.038: I/ActivityManager(276): Displayed doug.irrlicht/.IrrHelloWorld: +2s790ms
11-27 02:54:52.058: I/Choreographer(276): Skipped 101 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 02:54:52.139: I/Choreographer(276): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 02:54:52.288: I/Choreographer(406): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 02:54:52.418: I/Choreographer(276): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 02:54:52.998: I/Choreographer(276): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 02:54:53.508: I/Choreographer(954): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I got that there is error in GLView.java class, here is the GLView.java code:

```
    public GLView(Context context, boolean translucent, int depth, int stencil) {
        super(context);
        init(translucent, depth, stencil);
    }

    private void init(boolean translucent, int depth, int stencil) {


        if (translucent) {
            this.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        }


        setEGLContextFactory(new ContextFactory());


        setEGLConfigChooser( translucent ?
                             new ConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, depth, stencil) :
                             new ConfigChooser(5, 6, 5, 0, depth, stencil) );

        setRenderer(new Renderer());
    }

    private static class ContextFactory implements GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory {
        private static int EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION = 0x3098;
        public EGLContext createContext(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
            Log.w(TAG, "creating OpenGL ES 2.0 context");
            checkEglError("Before eglCreateContext", egl);
            int[] attrib_list = {EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL10.EGL_NONE };
            EGLContext context = egl.eglCreateContext(display, eglConfig, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attrib_list);
            checkEglError("After eglCreateContext", egl);
            return context;
        }

        public void destroyContext(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLContext context) {
            egl.eglDestroyContext(display, context);
        }
    }

    private static void checkEglError(String prompt, EGL10 egl) {
        int error;
        while ((error = egl.eglGetError()) != EGL10.EGL_SUCCESS) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s: EGL error: 0x%x", prompt, error));
        }
    }

    private static class ConfigChooser implements GLSurfaceView.EGLConfigChooser {

        public ConfigChooser(int r, int g, int b, int a, int depth, int stencil) {
            mRedSize = r;
            mGreenSize = g;
            mBlueSize = b;
            mAlphaSize = a;
            mDepthSize = depth;
            mStencilSize = stencil;
        }

        private static int EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT = 4;
        private static int[] s_configAttribs2 =
        {
            EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 4,
            EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 4,
            EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 4,
            EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
            EGL10.EGL_NONE
        };

        public EGLConfig chooseConfig(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display) {

            int[] num_config = new int[1];
            egl.eglChooseConfig(display, s_configAttribs2, null, 0, num_config);

            int numConfigs = num_config[0];

            if (numConfigs <= 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No configs match configSpec");
            }

            EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[numConfigs];
            egl.eglChooseConfig(display, s_configAttribs2, configs, numConfigs, num_config);

            if (DEBUG) {
                 printConfigs(egl, display, configs);
            }

            return chooseConfig(egl, display, configs);
        }

        public EGLConfig chooseConfig(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display,
                EGLConfig[] configs) {
            for(EGLConfig config : configs) {
                int d = findConfigAttrib(egl, display, config,
                        EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 0);
                int s = findConfigAttrib(egl, display, config,
                        EGL10.EGL_STENCIL_SIZE, 0);


                if (d < mDepthSize || s < mStencilSize)
                    continue;

                int r = findConfigAttrib(egl, display, config,
                        EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 0);
                int g = findConfigAttrib(egl, display, config,
                            EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 0);
                int b = findConfigAttrib(egl, display, config,
                            EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 0);
                int a = findConfigAttrib(egl, display, config,
                        EGL10.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 0);

                if (r == mRedSize && g == mGreenSize && b == mBlueSize && a == mAlphaSize)
                    return config;
            }
            return null;
        }

        private int findConfigAttrib(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display,
                EGLConfig config, int attribute, int defaultValue) {

            if (egl.eglGetConfigAttrib(display, config, attribute, mValue)) {
                return mValue[0];
            }
            return defaultValue;
        }

        private void printConfigs(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display,
            EGLConfig[] configs) {
            int numConfigs = configs.length;
            Log.w(TAG, String.format("%d configurations", numConfigs));
            for (int i = 0; i < numConfigs; i++) {
                Log.w(TAG, String.format("Configuration %d:\n", i));
                printConfig(egl, display, configs[i]);
            }
        }
```

And the error:

```
11-27 02:54:35.358: E/cutils-trace(927): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

I have done a lot to fix this, even I reinstalled my ADT, nothing changed, I will post my Manifest file if needed. Does anyone know how to fix this bug?

Comment: Fixed the bug in `chooseConfig:` by changing emulation option from `Snapshot` to `Use Host GPU`. Help me fix `Error opening trace file:  No such file or directory`.

Comment: No one knows how to solve this huh? Atleast say what topic should I learn to fix this?